# Django: SocialApp matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth, and I configured `localhost:9000/admin/`  with the following details:

```
socialapp .
provider:
Name:
Client id:
App ID, or consumer key
Key:
Secret:  etc .
```

I set `SITE_ID = 2` (because I changed the default site `example.com` to `localhost:9000`)

In settings.py:

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'uni_form',
        'allauth',
        'allauth.account',
        'allauth.socialaccount',
        'bootstrapform',
        # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
        # 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
         'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    )
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
        { 'facebook':
            { 'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
              'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'auth_type': 'reauthenticate' },
              'METHOD': 'oauth2' ,
              'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable'} }
```

When I go to:

```
http://localhost:9000/accounts/facebook/login
```

I get:

```
Error :  `SocialApp matching query does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using the Django admin you need to create a `SocialApp` listing your Facebook app credentials. Make sure that this app is attached to the proper site (as in, `django.contrib.sites.models.Site`).

In your case, there needs to be a `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` instance with id=2 (check the sites admin) that is listed as a site for the `SocialApp`.

If either the `SocialApp` is missing, or if it is created but not attached to a site matching your `settings.SITE_ID`, then `allauth` does not know what app to pick, resulting in the error message you listed above.

Comment: thanks author i was missing django.contrib.sites.models.Site  line

Comment: I couldn't get the admin panel to show my SITE's id, so I loaded it in a shell: `from django.contrib.sites.models import Site` and did a `Site.objects.all()` to see the list. `Site.objects.get(id=2)` was actually set to example, so I had to change my settings to 3, which was what my localhost was set to.

Comment: I was getting this error in testing.  This gave me a clue to the problem. In your set up you have to add from allauth.utils import  get_current_site from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp         sa = SocialApp.objects.create(name='Facebook', provider='facebook') sa.sites.add(get_current_site())

Comment: Addendum to above. I also had to add my app's actual client_id and secret for testing the login of a Facebook test user.

Comment: @AdamStarrh, to see the site ID in the admin panel just add `admin.site.unregister(Site)` and then  `class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): list_display = ('id', 'domain', 'name')` and  finally `admin.site.register(Site, SiteAdmin)` to your `admin.py` file.

Comment: I do this: `user$ python manage.py shell`. Then from within the interactive prompt, I issue the following two commands: `>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site` and then `>>> sorted([(site.id,site.name) for site in Site.objects.all()])`. The output looks like: `[(1, u'www.lvh.me'), (2, u'example.com'), (3, u'www.example.com'), (4, u'example.com:80'), (5, u'www.example.com:80')]`

Answer (score 19):

For me, it showed this error when I had in `settings.py`:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

It worked when I changed it to `2`:

```
SITE_ID = 2
```

Comment: For me i changed it to 3 and it worked.

Answer (score 19):

In my case, on the **Add social application** page, I forgot to select my site as `"Chosen sites"` ‍♂️

See screenshot below *(on the bottom right is the Chosen Sites list)*:
[image]

Comment: This worked after trying the other answers.

Answer (score 19):

**Step 1: Go to your admin page.**
Find `social application`

[image]

**Step 2: now add the lines like the following image.
Give your client id and secret key given by google api and move `available site (example.com)` to `chosen sites`**
[image]

**Step 3: Now go to `sites` in the side navigation of admin page and customize like the following image and save it**

[image]

**Step 4: now, add, `SITE_ID = 1` in settings.py file.**

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to putting that into the admin, you can also put it in your settings like so: (At least in 2022 with version django-allauth==0.45.0

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'discord': {
        # From https://developer.twitter.com
        'APP': {
            'client_id': os.environ['TWITTER_API_KEY'],
            'secret': os.environ['TWITTER_API_SECRET'],
            'key': os.environ['TWITTER_APP_ID'],
        }
    },
    'twitter': {
        # From https://developer.twitter.com
        'APP': {
            'client_id': os.environ['TWITTER_API_KEY'],
            'secret': os.environ['TWITTER_API_SECRET'],
            'key': os.environ['TWITTER_APP_ID'],
        }
    },
}
```

Documentation is at: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html and https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Django created an 'example.com' site for you already (if it's not a new project). So if this is the case you will need to delete that entry from the Sites admin page AND change the SITE_ID in settings.py to be the correct ID (probably 2 rather than 1).

Consider playing around with the SITE_ID value. For example: SITE_ID = 3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, if configuration via the DB is giving you problems, note that you can also use configuration in settings:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
"google": {
    "APP": {
        "client_id": os.environ[("GOOGLE_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"],
        "secret": os.environ[("GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET"],
    },
},
}
```

@Penners

Comment: You gave multiple answers to the same question. Edit your first answer to incorporate all information. Also note that some hints could be provided as comment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE' : [
            'profile',
            'email'
        ],
        'APP': {
            'client_id': os.environ['CLIENT_ID'],
            'secret': os.environ['CLIENT_SECRET'],
        },
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type':'online',
        }
    }
}
```