# Read The Docs Connect to Bitbucket

Tags: python, django, read-the-docs

I have a problem. I've instaled Read The Docs by manual but when I try to connect to bitbucket I get an error:

```
DoesNotExist at /accounts/bitbucket_oauth2/login/
enter code hereSocialApp matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/bitbucket_oauth2/login/?process=connect
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
SocialApp matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /home/administrator/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 334
Python Executable:  /home/administrator/rtd/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.9
Python Path:    
['/home/administrator/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/administrator/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org']
Server time:    Пт, 15 Июл 2016 08:19:53 -0500
```

A traceback http://dpaste.com/3J4AK6K. Please help. What I need to do? I'm newer in python and django.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409366/django-socialapp-matching-query-does-not-exist

Comment: @jape Unfortunately, it didn't help me. I had tried to add `SocialApp` but it has made new error `KeyError at /accounts/social/connections/`.