# Error implementing Django Allauth facebook login on Pythonanywhere : "SocialApp matching query does not exist"

Tags: django-allauth, pythonanywhere

I am trying to implement facebook login using django allauth on pythonanywhere.com.The code I am using works fine on localhost. But the same set of code does not work on pythonanywhere. When I click on the "Facebook Oauth" hyperlink on the login page it takes me to facebook site on localhost.However when I do the same thing on pythonanywhere it gives me following error:

"DoesNotExist at /accounts/facebook/login/
SocialApp matching query does not exist."

Request your support in identifying the root cause.

1.login template :

```
{% load socialaccount %}
{% block content %}
<a href="{% provider_login_url "facebook" method="oauth2" %}">Facebook OAuth2</a>
```

1. settings.py file :

   SITE_ID = 3
    SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {
    'facebook': {
    'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
    #'METHOD': 'js_sdk' ,
    'METHOD': 'oauth2',
    'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
    #'LOCALE_FUNC':  lambda request: return 'en-US',
    }
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: SocialApp matching query does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409366/django-socialapp-matching-query-does-not-exist)

Comment: In my case it's working fine on the localhost , however it doesn't work as desired on the pythonanywhere hosting platfrom

Comment: That's because you have the entry in the database on your machine and not on PythonAnywhere

Comment: Is there a particular entry that you are referring to? Because I have already done the required settings in admin console on pythonanywhere too(i.e. social account, social application and site id etc)